# How to load sprite sheets from web API in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sprite-sheet, texturepacker

I'm new to SpriteKit, and my question is how to load sprite sheets from web API.

Currently, I have an API returns a big PNG image, which contains all sprite sheets, and a json about individual frame information. (file and json are generated by [TexturePacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker)) The API looks like this:

[image]

The format just likes a `.atlasc` folder, which contains a big image and a plist (XML) file.

I was thinking about downloading image and plist file and save it in the disk to load. However, `SKTextureAtlas.init(named: String)` can only load from app bundle.

In one word, I want to load a sprite animation from the web at runtime.

I have control of the API, so I can update the API to accomplish my goal.

Comment: This is why extensions exist,  use SKTextureAtlas(dictionary:string:AnyObject) as your designated init

Comment: You mean I need to make API return individual images, I download them all and init a `SKTextureAtlas` with `init(dictionary: [String : AnyObject])`?

Comment: No, you download the other atlas (texture packer atlas) then you make individual textures out of it via code and place them using the method i said.  SkTexture allows you to extract a texture from a larder texture, so you load the main image as a texture,  then based on the json, you extract the individuals out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've figured out is downloading `image`, create a `sourceTexture`, like: `let sourceTexture = SKTexture(image: image)`

Then use the `frame` information in `json` to create individual textures with method `init(rect rect: CGRect, inTexture texture: SKTexture)`

Sample code is:

```swift
var textures: [SKTexture] = []

let sourceTexture = SKTexture(image: image)
for frame in spriteSheet.frames {
  let rect = CGRect(
    x: frame.frame.origin.x / spriteSheet.size.width,
    y:  1.0 - (frame.frame.size.height / spriteSheet.size.height) - (frame.frame.origin.y / spriteSheet.size.height),
    width: frame.frame.size.width / spriteSheet.size.width,
    height: frame.frame.size.height / spriteSheet.size.height
  )
  let texture = SKTexture(rect: rect, inTexture: sourceTexture)
  textures.append(texture)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

basically same way with @Honghao Zhang 's answer, but I was little bit confused about the whole structure at first glance.

so I share my code snippet for later readers.

Happy coding :)

```swift
    func getSpriteTextures() -> [SKTexture]? {
        guard let spriteSheet = loadSpriteJson(name: "sprite_json_file", codable: SpriteJson.self) else { return nil }
        let sourceImage = UIImage(named: "sprite_img_file.png")!
        let sourceTexture = SKTexture(image: sourceImage)
        var textures: [SKTexture] = []
        
        let sourceWidth = spriteSheet.meta.size.w
        let sourceHeight = spriteSheet.meta.size.h
        
        let orderedFrameImgNames = spriteSheet.frames.keys.sorted()
        
        for frameImgName in orderedFrameImgNames {
            let frameMeta = spriteSheet.frames[frameImgName]!
            let rect = CGRect(x: frameMeta.frame.x / sourceWidth,
                              y: 1.0
                                - (frameMeta.sourceSize.h / sourceHeight)
                                - (frameMeta.frame.y / sourceHeight),
                              width: frameMeta.frame.w / sourceWidth,
                              height: frameMeta.frame.h / sourceHeight)
            let texture = SKTexture(rect: rect, in: sourceTexture)
            textures.append(texture)
        }
        return textures
    }
```

Comment: Hard to understand this without the code for loadSpriteJson & SpriteJson